# How to build M to M relationships between two data model

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

Condition:

Tutor can follow or dis-follow student

Student can follow or dis-follow tutor

Tutor and Student are two different data models.

I build a middle data model called`application` connecting both model

Application model:

```
class CreateApplications < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :applications do |t|

      t.belongs_to :tutor, index: true
      t.belongs_to :student, index: true

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

application.rb

```
class Application < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :tutor
    belongs_to :student
end
```

student.rb

```
  has_many :applications, :dependent => :destroy
   has_many :tutors,   through: :applications
```

tutor.rb

```
   has_many :applications, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :students, through: :applications
```

schema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20170421093747) do

  create_table "applications", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "tutor_id"
    t.integer  "student_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  add_index "applications", ["student_id"], name: "index_applications_on_student_id"
  add_index "applications", ["tutor_id"], name: "index_applications_on_tutor_id".......
```

show.html.erb

```
# -->show who is the follower & person who followed & How many of them
# Error :undefined method `student' for nil:NilClass


     <%= @application.student.count %>  #undefined method `student' for nil:NilClass
     <%= @application.tutor.count % >#undefined method `student' for nil:NilClass

     <%= @application.student%> #undefined method `student' for nil:NilClass
```

Comment: Your @application variable is nil. Can you please post the relevant controller code where this is being set?

Comment: @mysmallidea `class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  include SessionsHelper
  include SecondsessionsHelper
end
`nothing inside

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code there instead of showing it in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

In your controller, you need to set the @application variable.

```
def show
  @application = Application.find(params[:id])
end
```

I would strongly advise against naming this class `Application`. The word "Application" has special meaning in Rails and you will almost certainly run into conflicts. Same goes for `ApplicationController`.

Comment: Then ,I should put the above code on the original `ApplicationController` or a new create `ApplicationController`?

Comment: You should start over with a new controller and model, destroying the controller and model named "Application" that you just created. Ruby has many reserved words.  By avoiding using them as names you will save yourself a lot of headache. https://reservedwords.herokuapp.com/.

Answer (score 0):

When model has many relationship with other model you want to use plural name, i.e. tutor.students or student.tutors

UPD: Also, you didn't pass variable into view properly, check your controller.

UPD1: Also, it's meaningless to use count on application record (btw you want to rename it to something like Courses, Classes or just StudentTutor because Application.rb is the model all your models inherit from by default, same goes to ApplicationController).  It always has one student and one tutor (it belongs to both models). If you want to count related records you want to find student (if you want to count his tutors) or tutor (for vise-versa)

Comment: u mean as `application` attributes` ?

Comment: I mean as model public method that returns an array of related active records. That's how Rails convention works on specifying has_many and belongs_to relationship. You don't need to explicitly do anything with application, since you've specified has_many though already.